PySpark code function to add column in spark dataframe
I want to  directly add 3 new columns to my PySpark dataframe(w/o converting to pandas dataframe)- 'inferenced_data' : Level_L1, Level_L2,Alert_Reason. The value for these columns needs to be filled from the values returned by  the below function:
****Input values passed to the function:****

topics = ['Critical','Insight']

themes = ['escalation_fg','process_fg']

reasons = ['reason_escalation_fg','reason_process_fg']

l2_themes = ['CRC','Process']


    def set_alert_priority(row, topics, themes, reasons, l2_themes):
        num_alerts_tagged = len([c for c in themes if row[c] == 1])
        row_sum = sum([row[c] for c in themes])
    
        if num_alerts_tagged == 0:
            return ('No Action Taken', 'No Action Taken', 'No Action Taken')
        elif row_sum == -25:
            return ('GPT Error', 'GPT Error', 'GPT Error')
        else:
            for topic, theme, reason, l2_theme in zip(topics, themes, reasons, l2_themes):
                if row[theme] == 1:
                    return (topic, l2_theme, row[reason])

    inferenced_data[['Level_L1', 'Level_L1', 'Alert_Reason']] = inferenced_data.apply(lambda row : set_alert_priority(row, topics, themes, reasons, l2_themes), axis=1)

But while doing so I am getting the error as "Attribute apply is not supported."
I guess this is because the 'apply' method is not for Spark dataframe? What can be an alternative in this case?

In PySpark, the apply method is not available as it is in pandas. Instead, you can achieve your goal using a combination of a user-defined function (UDF) or withColumn in PySpark
I am more comfortable with withColumn. So I give you this solution.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AddColumnsExample").getOrCreate()

# Sample input data
data = [
    {"escalation_fg": 1, "process_fg": 0, "reason_escalation_fg": "Escalation Reason", "reason_process_fg": "Process Reason"},
    {"escalation_fg": 0, "process_fg": 1, "reason_escalation_fg": "No Reason", "reason_process_fg": "Process Escalation"},
    {"escalation_fg": 0, "process_fg": 0, "reason_escalation_fg": "None", "reason_process_fg": "None"}
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# Topics and Themes
topics = ["Critical", "Insight"]
l2_themes = ["CRC", "Process"]

# Add `Level_L1` column
df = df.withColumn(
    "Level_L1",
    when((col("escalation_fg") == 1), lit(topics[0]))
    .when((col("process_fg") == 1), lit(topics[1]))
    .otherwise(lit("No Action Taken"))
)

# Add `Level_L2` column
df = df.withColumn(
    "Level_L2",
    when((col("escalation_fg") == 1), lit(l2_themes[0]))
    .when((col("process_fg") == 1), lit(l2_themes[1]))
    .otherwise(lit("No Action Taken"))
)

# Add `Alert_Reason` column
df = df.withColumn(
    "Alert_Reason",
    when((col("escalation_fg") == 1), col("reason_escalation_fg"))
    .when((col("process_fg") == 1), col("reason_process_fg"))
    .otherwise(lit("No Action Taken"))
)

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df.show()

